# Google plus SSO sign out functionality in android app

Tags: android, google-plus

I know how to perform action on for SSO using Google Plus in android. I am successfully able to login app using same.

Now I need to log out user so that he/ she can log in app again using Google plus with a new account. I need to do same in another activity.

I have tried using **disconnect()** method but with no success.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can find in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) how to sign out the user. The relevant part is this:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
      mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

Comment: Yeah I  know this stuff but not able to sign out user from other class. Means say I logged in using Login.java class and need to sign out from UserProfile.java class... Getting NUll point exception over there ..

Comment: hmm... I assume that you need to initialize the `mGoogleAPiClient` somewhere where both activities have access to. For example, create a class called `BaseActivity` that will initialize the google api client, and both `Login` and `UserProfile` activities will extend it, and be able to access the google api client.